# Isn't this math about a parallelogram wrong?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

[image: math]

This is the math(b). I think this math is wrong as both OA and OC are parallel to the x-axis; it is impossible for two adjacent sides of a parallelogram to be parallel. So, isn't the math wrong?

Comment: $OC$ is not parallel to $X$-axis. The equation of $OC$ is given to be $y = 2x$. That is a line through the origin with slope $2$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I totally didn't read that properly; that's what doing maths from 6 AM does to you. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of $OC$ is $y=2x$ which means it will pass through $x$ axis at $(0,0)$ so $OC$ is not parallel to $x$ axis.